# SSL error when trying to connect to local Caddy server

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, caddy, mercure

I have setup a Mercure hub from Symfony/api-platform.
Mercure hub is being served via Caddy over SSL (e.g. https://example.com/.well-known/mercure).
Caddy is a dockerized service.

I am trying to build a golang microservice on the **same docker-compose file**, that aims to connect to Mercure hub.
This microservice `go_sse_listener` is trying to connect to Mercure hub via docker's insternal network but fails with an ssl error

I connected to `go_sse_listener` and issued a curl command, to get more input

```
curl -v -L -N -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxx" https://caddy/.well-known/mercure?topic=%2F.well-known%2Fmercure%2Fsubscriptions%7B%2Ftopic%7D%7B%2Fsubscriber%7D
```

**response/error**:

```
*   Trying 172.20.0.3:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to caddy (172.20.0.3) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, internal error (592):
* error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error
* Closing connection 1
curl: (35) error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

this is my production docker-compose.prod:yml

```
version: "3.4"
services:

  caddy:
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost, caddy:80}
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY}
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY}
      MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES: |
        demo
  
  go_sse_listener:
    build:
      context: microservices
    container_name: go_listener
```

and my Caddyfile

```
{
    # Debug
    {$DEBUG}
    # HTTP/3 support
    servers {
        protocol {
            experimental_http3
        }
    }
}

{$SERVER_NAME}

log

# Matches requests for HTML documents, for static files and for Next.js files,
# except for known API paths and paths with extensions handled by API Platform
@pwa expression `(
        {header.Accept}.matches("\\btext/html\\b")
        && !{path}.matches("(?i)(?:^/docs|^/graphql|^/bundles/|^/_profiler|^/_wdt|\\.(?:json|html$|csv$|ya?ml$|xml$))")
    )
    || {path} == "/favicon.ico"
    || {path} == "/manifest.json"
    || {path} == "/robots.txt"
    || {path}.startsWith("/_next")
    || {path}.startsWith("/sitemap")`

route {
    root * /srv/api/public
    mercure {
        # Transport to use (default to Bolt)
        transport_url {$MERCURE_TRANSPORT_URL:bolt:///data/mercure.db}
        # Publisher JWT key
        publisher_jwt {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG}
        # Subscriber JWT key
        subscriber_jwt {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG}
        # Allow anonymous subscribers (double-check that it's what you want)
        anonymous
        # Enable the subscription API (double-check that it's what you want)
        subscriptions
        # Extra directives
        {$MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}
    }
    vulcain
    push

    # Add links to the API docs and to the Mercure Hub if not set explicitly (e.g. the PWA)
    header ?Link `</docs.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation", </.well-known/mercure>; rel="mercure"`
    # Disable Google FLOC tracking if not enabled explicitly: https://plausible.io/blog/google-floc
    header ?Permissions-Policy "interest-cohort=()"

    # Comment the following line if you don't want Next.js to catch requests for HTML documents.
    # In this case, they will be handled by the PHP app.
    reverse_proxy @pwa http://{$PWA_UPSTREAM}

    php_fastcgi unix//var/run/php/php-fpm.sock
    encode zstd gzip
    file_server
}
```

From what I understand:
When `go_sse_listener` docker requests the caddy domain. It correctly resolves it to the appropriate caddy container local ip, in this case: 172.20.0.3,
but when caddy catches the result it tries to resolve it to a domain or host named caddy with an ssl, which it knows nothing about and thus the error.